# Duvidas com comandos condicionais em arquivos Batch

Tags: cmd, batch, bat

O Intento é copiar arquivos **.jpg** para uma sub-pasta chamada **\imagem**, e os demais, digo, arquivos diferentes de **.jpg**, para a pasta **\Nova pasta (2)\**.

> Só que não está funcionando, o que pode estar errado?

Abaixo o código **batch** que estou utilizando:

```bat
cls
@echo COPIANDO ARQUIVOS JPEG

for %%f in (*.*) do (
    if %%f equ *.jpg ( 
       copy %%f "C:\Users\anezio\Desktop\Nova pasta (2)\imagem"
      ) else (
       copy %%f "C:\Users\anezio\Desktop\Nova pasta (2)"
      )
 )
pause
```

Comment: Qual o erro que você está encontrando? O que você espera que aconteça, e o que está acontecendo?

Comment: Na verdade o arquivo, quando executado, não atende a primeira condição (onde deve copiar arquivos .jpg para a pasta imagem), executando somente a copia após o 'else'.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa usar um modificador para obter a extensão do arquivo. Você nunca terá um arquivo chamado `*.jpg`, o que é o que você está comparando. Usando o modificador `~x` como mostrado abaixo deve resolver o seu problema.

```
cls
@echo COPIANDO ARQUIVOS JPEG

for %%f in (*.*) do (
if %%~xf equ .jpg ( 
copy %%f "C:\Users\anezio\Desktop\Nova pasta (2)\imagem"
) else (
copy %%f "C:\Users\anezio\Desktop\Nova pasta (2)"
)
)
pause
```

Comment: Obrigado pela força e atenção carlosfigueira, mas não deu certo amigo =/

Comment: Se puder me explicar como funciona esse esquema de modificador ficarei muito grato.

Comment: Dá uma olhada na documentação do comando `for` do batch: `for /?`. Você vai achar a lista de todos os modificadores que ele suporta. Por exemplo: `%~xf`: extensão; `%~nf`: nome do arquivo...

Answer (score 1):

::issae

```
    cls
    @echo COPIANDO ARQUIVOS JPEG

    for %%f in (*.*) do (
            if "%%~xf" equ ".jpg" ( 
                    copy %%f "C:\Users\anezio\Desktop\Nova pasta (2)\imagem"
                    ) else (
                    copy %%f "C:\Users\anezio\Desktop\Nova pasta (2)"
                    )
            )
    pause
```

Comment: Boa noite. Poderia explicar a sua resposta?

Answer (score 1):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**1)** faz um loop for listando todos os arquivos em pastas e sub pastas (dir /s ..)

**2)** verifica se eh um jpg e caso positivo/negativo, copia p pasta de destino 
   atendendo o filtro

**3)** implementado um contador p jpg, outros e total

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

cd /d "%~dp0" & cls && color 0a & mode con cols=100 lines=8

set _cnt_jpg=0
set _cnt_outros=0
set /a _cnt_total=!_cnt_jpg! + !_cnt_outros!

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%f in ('dir /a:-d /b /s *.*') do ( 

    echo/ && Title Arquivos Copiados !_show_cnt_total:~-7! ...

    (

    <nul echo/%%f | findstr /i /l /c:".jpg" 

    ) 2>nul 
    if "!errorlevel!" == "0"  (

         set /a "_cnt_jpg=!_cnt_jpg! + 1" & copy "%%~f" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Nova pasta (2)\imagem\" /v /y >nul 2>nul

        ) else (

         set /a "_cnt_outros=!_cnt_outros! + 1" & copy "%%~f" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Nova pasta (2)\" /v /y >nul 2>nul

        )

      echo. && echo/ COPIANDO ARQUIVOS JPEG... 

      set /a _cnt_total=!_cnt_jpg! + !_cnt_outros!
      set "_show_cnt_jpg=000000!_cnt_jpg!"&& echo/ Arquivos .jpgs copiados: !_show_cnt_jpg:~-7!
      set "_show_cnt_outros=000000!_cnt_outros!"&& echo/ Arquivos n jpg copiados: !_show_cnt_outros:~-7!
      Echo/ --------------------------------
      set "_show_cnt_total=000000!_cnt_total!"&& echo/ Totalizado jpg + outros: !_show_cnt_total:~-7!

    )
```